Trying to create a layer that uses the results of a distance and intersection calculation
I am trying to create a layer that reflects the results of two different calculations. The first is a distance calculation using a buffer of the number of polygons from one dataset and then the second is whether these polygons intersect with those of another dataset. Ideally, I would like to have one final layer that can combine the total derived from the distance calculation and whether the polygon does or does not intersect.

What GIS software are you using?
